# Getting the column name of table onChange event

Tags: office-js

**Task:**

Using the OnChange event of a table object, detect which column and row of that particular table changed.

Currently I have the following code, which works and is likely fairly efficient, however I wondered if there was a simpler alternative? Because this really seems like something that should be built into the event object itself...

```
async function registerOnChangeEvent(tableName,callback) {
    return await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        const pointsTab = context.workbook.tables.getItem(tableName);
        const headers = pointsTab.getHeaderRowRange().load("values");
        const headersAdd = pointsTab.getHeaderRowRange().load("address");
        await context.sync();

        //Register event
        pointsTab.onChanged.add((event)=>{
            return Excel.run(function(context){ 
                return context.sync()
                    .then(function () {
                        //event, context, this
                        //console.log(event, context, this)
                        var rootData  = headersAdd.address.match(/\!([A-Z]+)(\d+)/)
                        var rootCol   = getColumnIndex(rootData[1])
                        var rootRow   = parseInt(rootData[2])
                        var eventData = event.address.match(/([A-Z]+)(\d+)/)
                        var eventCol  = getColumnIndex(eventData[1])
                        var eventRow  = parseInt(eventData[2])

                        //column name and number from event and root data.
                        event["colNum"] = eventCol - rootCol;
                        event["colName"] = headers.values[0][event["colNum"]];
                        event["rowNum"] = eventRow - rootRow;

                        console.log(event)
                        callback(event); //If required.
                    })
            }).catch(function () {
                //...
            })
        })
        return
    });
}

function getColumnIndex(address) {
    const alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    var arr = address.split("")
    var sum = 0
    arr.forEach((char, index) => {
        var i = arr.length - index - 1
        sum = sum + (alphabet.indexOf(char) + 1) * Math.pow(alphabet.length, i)
    })
    return sum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your asking and using our API. Let me double confirm your requirement. Your needs are the column/row index of the table from the event argument, right? That's what we are considering too.

But one problem is that when you changed some discontinue range(like A4 and B5 [Discontinue Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnDEr.png)), it will return the address "A4,B5" in one event. The discontinue range are splitted by the comma. So we can't just return the index and width/length only for "A4" or "B5". So maybe we could return the column/row index lists and width/length lists like

```
EventArgument {
    ...
    address: "A4, B5",
    columnIndexes: [1, 2],
    rowIndexes: [1, 2],
    weigths: [1, 1],
    lengths: [1, 1],
    ...
}
```

or

```
EventArgument {
    address: "A4, B5",
    Indexes: [[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1, 1]]
}
```

or ...

It seems either of them is complex. It might be great if you can share your ideas about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Traditionally, in a C++ environment, I would expect 2 events to be raised, one for `A4` and the other for `B5`. I can understand though the desire to group events which occur in the same calc event. In this case I'd suggest rather: `EventArgument:{ranges:[{address:"A4",columnIndex: 1, rowIndex:3, width:1, length:1},{address:"B5",columnIndex:2, rowIndex:4, width:1, length:1}, ...]}`

Comment: For that reason though I'd also suggest that all EventArguments be formatted this way, not only those of discontinued ranges.